# How to troubleshoot or roll back NVIDIA driver that breaks the system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, dell

A software update on Ubuntu 18.04 (Dell Precision, out of the box) broke my ability to log in.  When I looked at the Xorg log file I found an error about it not finding an NVIDIA driver, and then the error:

```
FBDEV(0): FBIOPUTCMAP: Device or resource busy
```

Repeated 256 times followed by a segfault.  This causes my attempt to log in to fail, leaving me back at the login prompt.  When I dug into it further, I discovered that the issue was an upgrade from the nvidia-driver-430 to nvidia-driver-440.  However, after purging all nvidia drivers, I found that I was unable to simply install the -430 driver.  Whenever I attempted to do so, apt-get indicated that it was about to install the -440 drivers instead.

I tried several things including editing /etc/defaults/grub, disabling the Wayland login, running ubuntu-devices to install non-free drivers, etc. but nothing worked. I am rather at my wits ends after wasting a whole day trying to fix this so it seems the only solution for now is to never allow a -440 update from the factory install, but this is rather difficult as there are 40 separate NVIDIA packages that have to be manually de-selected (they aren't all under one nice tree where I can click only one or two boxes).  Additionally, it is rather disheartening that if I every accidentally or unwittingly accept an update it can lock me out of the GPU until I do a full factory reinstall, which will be much more inconvenient one I have other stuff on the drive.

How can I troubleshoot this issue, or alternatively, roll back an update such as this when it prevents me from using my machine?

Comment: Sounds like a rant. We don't like those. Anyway, boot to Recovery Mode and type `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii` and either edit that output into your question, or screenshot it, or take a good picture with your phone, and post it here.

Comment: @heynnema Didn't mean it to sound like a rant, although my frustrating may be showing.  I can't provide the exact output at the moment as I have already done yet another system restore after somehow accidentally upgrading the driver again.